# Initialize base class’s fields in subclass constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, subclass, base-class

I have a base class with three field, but instead of initializing its field the normal way like this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ParentClass(string Name, string Family, string Address)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Family = Family;
        this.Address = Address;

    }

}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int StudentScore { get; set; }

    public ChildClass(string Name, string Family, string Address, int StudentID, int StudentScore)
        : base(Name, Family, Address)
    {

        this.StudentID = StudentID;
        this.StudentScore = StudentScore;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Pro = new ChildClass("John", "Greene", "45 Street", 76, 25);
        Console.WriteLine(Pro.Name + Pro.Family + Pro.Address + Pro.StudentID + Pro.StudentScore);
    }
}
```

I’ve initialized the fields in the ChildClass constructor without explicitly calling the base class constructor like this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int StudentScore { get; set; }

    public ChildClass(int StudentID, int StudentScore)
    {
        Name = "John";
        Family = "Greene";
        Address = "45 Street";
        this.StudentID = StudentID;
        this.StudentScore = StudentScore;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Pro = new ChildClass(76, 25);
        Console.WriteLine(Pro.Name + Pro.Family + Pro.Address + Pro.StudentID + Pro.StudentScore);
    }
}
```

I know I could have initialized the parent class’s field in the parent class itself and this is a bogus example, but I was wondering if it is considered a good practice to do something like that in real life and more complex situations, is there any reason why I shouldn’t do something like this? as to not explicitly call the base class constructor?

**Edit:** I'm more concerned about not explicitly call the base class constructor and initializing it in subclass part, so I've edited the last part that mentioned the fields being exposed out.

Comment: if you want have access or use the fields of `parentClass` inside `chieldClass` you have to expose them to `chieldClass` i.e: by making them `protected` or `public`, so what's the problem? I think your question in completely meaningless  and is not useful at all!!!!!!!

Comment: I was more concerned about not explicitly call the base class constructor part, which you didn't pay any attention to it, I've edited the last part out to avoid more confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already seen, the fields are *already* "exposed". Your could still get to those variables from the derived class in the first example.

As to not using a base class constructor being good practice, I would say not. By only having a parameterized base class constructor, you are making sure that future implementers of that class initialize the base class properties. For example, in your second I could write:

```
public ChildClass(int StudentID, int StudentScore)
{
    this.StudentID = StudentID;
    this.StudentScore = StudentScore;
}
```

With no errors. Other than that there are very few differences between your samples.

Comment: Yes, you've addressed the both part, I've edited the last part out to avoid getting anymore down-vote from "down-vote happy" shall I say, people, sorry for that, but this place is not beginner friendly, why should I get a down-vote when my question isn't a duplicated one?

Comment: @Xellarix I didn't downvote, but from the comment you received, it looks like two people felt it wasn't useful because you misunderstood that *both* classes had those fields "exposed" while missing the part about the constructor. Given that misunderstanding, I can see a "not useful" downvote when the question doesn't really make sense. Note that "not being a duplicate" is not the only condition for voting.